# Stackoverflow like tag system form for django?

Tags: django, django-forms

What I am trying to create is a site for resources. Basically, you add resources such as books and videos via links. Now, with any resource site that caters to a variety of resources, you need to tag them in order to understand what kind of resource you are using.

For example, if you make notes on something like Chemistry or key points from a talk on lets say "Django", then these are text documents. Thus you would want them inside a `TEXT` TAG.

So, when you are making a form for this kind of thing, what form field would you use? For example, by knee-jerk approach is to simple make a text area field, and then separate the different tags via comma. Now, this can be prone to many problems, I'd just like to know what is the best approach to take to solving this problem? Basically, an easy way to validate the data input? Would `forms.ChoiceField` be the best approach to the problem or is there something else that is superior?

Comment: How is this off topic? I just asked for type of form element I should use. I'm already using a manytomany field for the tags. Whats wrong with this question?

Comment: Changed the question, should be "on-topic" by now.

Comment: I disagree with closing this question, I think it's perfectly on-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/tagging/ is your best bet, most specifically https://github.com/alex/django-taggit. If you want to run your own tagging system, take a look at the source code for some ideas.

EDIT: The easiest way to display this in a form would be to use a `ModelMultipleChoiceField`. This allows you to select multiple tags for a single resource, and handles server-side validation and conversion to the actual `Tag` instances. However, I think most people would agree this option looks hideous, and it is certainly not user-friendly if there is a large amount of possible tags.

If you're using jQUery, another option is to use [Django_select2](http://django-select2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). This is what I have personally used in a similar situation, and it handles a large amount of possible tags very well. Django_select2 is a thin wrapper around jQuery's Select2 plugin, with a bit of added functionality (most notably the `AutoView` and `AutoModelSelect2Field`). This provides a hybrid between a text field and a select list, allowing you to search all tags and easily select multiple tags. See http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ for examples of what you can achieve.